# MAMP PHP vs Apple's installed version

Tags: php, terminal, version, mamp

I would like to use MAMP's version of PHP for my local PHP testing and development. I understand that Macs come with a version of PHP installed. I have installed MAMP and everything seems to be going smoothly except error reporting.

In Terminal I have checke which version of PHP my machine is using and it is not the one from MAMP. I have changed MAMP's php.ini files to report all errors. I am not getting any errors in my testing. I am inserting obvious errors to test for.

My questions are: 
How can I disable or remove the preinstalled version of PHP?
How can I set my machine to use only MAMP's version of PHP?
Can I test multiple versions of PHP at once? Is it recommended?
How can I stay up to date with the latest version of PHP? Is it like normal Software Updates?

-Josh

Comment: I also just moved to Mac recently and installed MAMP. Which worked perfect. No issue of using Mac's php version, MAMP comes with two version of PHP by default  MAMP Control Panel comes with preference, where you can select which version of php you want use. Each version has different php.ini. There are chances you are editing wrong php.ini. What steps did you follow installing MAMP ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rasikh. I have verified the version of php I am running in MAMP and I have verified the associated .ini file. Curiously, I checked `php --version` in Terminal and it returned `5.3.15`, which is not even a choice in MAMP. I hypothesize that the installed version of php is running and taking precendence of my php operations despite MAMP open and running with its own set of correctly configured preferences. I need to be able to shut down the installed version and only use MAMP's version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add/change following line in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc (for bash):
>   export
>   PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/opt/local/bin
>   and after that please re-login (or just execute e.g. /bin/bash).

From http://drupal.org/node/1464236

You can change the version # to the version you want.